# How to fix SERVICE_PAUSED error on starting nssm server

Tags: nssm

So I need to run a custom server. It worked on other machines, but not on mine (all of them are on Windows).

My input:

```
nssm start custom-server
```

Error message:

```
custom-server: Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED in response to START control.
```

I tried to re-start it, but got the same message.

Comment: The problem should be the installation command. What is your install command ? Do you execute it in cmd or in script like batch file ?

Answer (score 29):

Use the following instructions to change I/O redirects:

```
nssm set [SERVICE_NAME] AppStdout [APP_PATH_INSTALL]\logs\service.log
nssm set [SERVICE_NAME] AppStderr [APP_PATH_INSTALL]\logs\service-error.log
```

Check the service log files to find the failure.

In my case, the failure was caused by a dependency on Python libraries.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me find the issue. In my case, it was that there was a problem with the quote escaping on my file path. To simplify things, I just moved it to a path that didn't have spaces so I could omit the quotes.

Comment: Note: if you enter a plain logfile name like "service.log", nssm will give an error in the system event viewer like "Registry key AppDirectory is unset for service <servicename>. Assuming startup directory C:\WINDOWS."

Comment: Can also do this through graphical interface if we do `nssm edit [SERVICE_NAME]`

Answer (score 7):

As Garric15 states it is probably your install command.

This could be for example a StdOut redirect to a path / file that does not exist on your local machine.

Look in the Application event log for errors where the source is **nssm** around the time you installed the service.

Comment: I have the same problem, and there are no errors in the install command.  It happens when starting more than ~16 services.  The first ~16 start successfully, and then the rest start as "paused".

Comment: Bizarrely, while this consistently happens for both LocalSystem and NetworkService, changing the logon to Administrator solves it.

Comment: I got the same problem, eventually I found that the my "custom-server" was faulty and could not start. Starting "custom-server" on its own revealed the real culprit.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bad syntax/entry somewhere along your code, could be an issue with the path or arguments, I'd test the service manually a bunch before putting on NSSM, make sure you have the correct flags/options
You can also set Standard Output through NSSM and that would give you a clue of what's going on.
If there's anything that'd interrupt the dependencies for that service to run, you'd also get that error.

This is how I install a service using NSSM with Powershell (make sure nssm is added to the PATH):

```
nssm.exe install "SERVICE NAME" "PATH TO FILE"
nssm.exe set "SERVICE NAME" AppParameters "<CHECK YOUR FILE OPTIONS>"
nssm.exe set "SERVICE NAME" AppStderr "PATH TO SAVE OUTPUT"
nssm.exe start "SERVICE NAME"
```

If you or anyone happens to see this post and need assistance, I can probably help you, just post more details on what needs to be done and what you're EXACTLY trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because firewall is blocking the software which you are running as a service, start first software separately, it will ask you to add to firewall exclusions , then you can use it via nssm

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that after the service was installed using **nssm.exe**, the program name was changed. This caused service to always go to *paused* state after start or restart the service, using either services.msc or nssm.exe command line.
Editing service nssm.exe startup parameters solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Some scenario

1. App directory not provided or doesn't exist

   ```
   nssm nssm set xyz-service AppDirectory "D:\Work\ShoppingKart"
   ```
2. File which is given for service may be corrupted (rebuild code)
3. The application trying to run is not proper or corrupted. Try to run without windows service once.
4. Program (.exe) file path not found (in this case look for the solution, or else give full path, if java not found even if it is there in env, just add full path)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using no `mws` (Managed Windows Service?) release,

ex.

`gogs_0.12.10_windows_amd64` works

`gogs_0.12.10_windows_amd64_mws` not working

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was there had been a Java update on my machine.  The JAVA_HOME environment variable was now pointing to an invalid directory (i.e. the old Java version).  Just needed to update the JAVA_HOME path and restart the solr services to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to configure rclone as a windows 10 service. I fixed it including the rclone.conf archive inside the rclone folder.